# React/Babel embedded: unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

fellow coders :)

So I just started to learn ReactJs and in the first 20 minutes ran into this error:

```
browser.js:62790 Uncaught SyntaxError: embedded: Unexpected token (9:3)
   7 |                  </div>
   8 |              },
>  9 |          )};
     |    ^
  10 |          React.render(<HelloWorld />, document.body);
  11 |
```

My code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/t39.3284-6/11057025_805715566176382_77439371_n.js"></script>
    <!-- version 0.13.3.min.js-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.29/browser.js"></script>
    <title>React</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/babel">
    var HelloWorld = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
            return <div>
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
            <p>This is some text</p>
        </div>
        }
    )};
    React.render(<HelloWorld />, document.body);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Looked around, didn't find anything that fixed that. Any ideas?I am sure this is a simple thing, but I am just starting out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your brackets are slightly off, see the last line of your component definition:

```
var HelloWorld = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <div>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <p>This is some text</p>
    </div>
    }
});
```

Comment: How to feel stupid in one simple step.. Thanks a lot, TimoSta :)

Answer (score 3):

You did't correctly wrap closing brace of render method.Your code should as follows:

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <head>
     <script src="https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/t39.3284-  6/11057025_805715566176382_77439371_n.js"></script>
    <!-- version 0.13.3.min.js-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.29/browser.js"></script>
    <title>React</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/babel">
    var HelloWorld = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
            return (<div>
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
            <p>This is some text</p>
        </div>);
        }
    });
    React.render(<HelloWorld />, document.body);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Best of Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the brackets

```
var HelloWorld = React.createClass({
render: function() {
    return <div>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <p>This is some text</p>
</div>
}
});
```